# Feature flag feature inside android?

Tags: android

There are multiple ways of implementing feature flag handling in java, but is there any specific solution in android?

What I've found is, there are https://developer.android.com/work/managed-configurations. configurations that you set and change, so the app can set/change it's behavior. it sounds quiet similar to a feature flag handling, but there is neither feature nor flag mentioned in that article.

Comment: What do you mean by feature-flag? Is it flag that is used as boolean value true/false ?

Comment: Hi Chintan, my usecase is, that I want to change behavior of an app from remote, like changing an app that behaves with basic features to an app with premium features.The flag can be true/false or an enum like basic/premium/ultra/mega etc. I know there are a lots of tutorial about implementing feature-flag-architectures in java, but I want to know if android does have any architecture or mechanism by it's own handling such kind of problem, like flavors but for changes in runtime.


thx

Comment: I don't think so that inside android there is such functionality available. But you can use firebase in that case which can be integrated with you android-app. You can modify mobile-front on change of firebase update call just like socket api calling.

Comment: oh thx, I will have a look!

Comment: I'm thinking of defining key/values-pairs on system (aosp) level, which can be set via SystemProperties. Similar to the feature-flags-implementation in the developer settings in android. That would work, but how to listen to changes, made in to the SystemProperties? Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

There is also [Firebase Remote Config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config) which allows you to change configuration values remotely. Firebase takes care of synchronising the data and updating the app accordingly.

This can easily be used to enabled/disabled features using boolean values.

Firebase is very much for Android, but not exclusively so you can use this same configuration mechanism for other platforms too.